# Merge files based on common column (but containing different number of records) and put zeros for uncommon records

Tags: perl, bash

I am stuck up at a very intriguing part of my Perl code, where I have to merge multiple files based on a common column, but this common column contains different number of records, i.e some records may exist in one file, but not in other and so on.

For example : Here are  my three files :

FileA.txt

```
ID  Value
 1   45
 2   56
 3   23
```

FileB.txt

```
ID  Value
 2   57
 3   65
 5   32
```

FileC.txt

```
ID  Value
 1   21
 3   68
 4   42
```

My output should be a combined table as follows :

```
ID  ValueA  ValueB  ValueC
 1   45       0      21
 2   56       57     0
 3   23       65     68
 4    0       0      42
 5    0       32     0
```

I tried using `paste` but that just pastes the lists side by side, without considering common columns.

How should I go about it ?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts so far, and the code that doesn't work as expected?  Your original title mentioned bash, where does shell scripting come into play?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash of hashes to remember the partial tables. The main key is the ID, the key of the inner hash is the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my %table;
for my $letter (qw(A B C)) {
    open my $IN, '<', "File$letter.txt" or die "Cannot open: $!";
    <$IN>; # Skip the header
    while (<$IN>) {
        my ($id, $value) = split;
        $table{$id}{$letter} = $value;
    }
}

say "ID\tValueA\tValueB\tValueC";
for my $id (keys %table) {
    say $id, join"\t", q(), map $table{$id}{$_} // 0, qw(A B C);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a hash (with the ID as the key), and read each file. When you are reading the FileA.txt, put something like this ($id and $value are the values you get from file):

```
$my_hash{$id} = {VALUE_A=>$value, VALUE_B=>0, VALUE_C=>0};
```

when reading FileB.txt, for each line:

```
if( exists $my_hash{$id} ) {
  $my_hash{$id}->{VALUE_B=>$value};
}
else {
   $my_hash{$id} = {VALUE_A=>0, VALUE_B=>$value, VALUE_C=>0};
}
```

quite similar for FileC.txt:

```
if( exists $my_hash{$id} ) {
  $my_hash{$id}->{VALUE_C=>$value};
}
else {
   $my_hash{$id} = {VALUE_A=>0, VALUE_B=>0, VALUE_C=>$value};
}
```

and finally, you have all your data in %my_hash